# recoger valor select y hacer consulta a sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql

llevo desde el domingo pegandome con esto y nada.

tengo unos select y me gustaria recoger el valor del 3º que eso lo hago con un

```
var id = $('#Ciudad').val()
```

bien, al recoger ese ID, enviarlo por post a un php, que haga la consulta en la sql y devuelta los valores consultados en el select php en una tabla, eh probado 1000 cosas, pero no lo consigo...

Este es el codigo que tengo ahora:

```
$("#ciudad_id").change(function(){
  $("#Validar").show();


                

  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
  type: "GET",
  url: "display.php",             
  dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
  success: function(response){                    
  $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
  //alert(response);
```

}

});

});

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre actualmente? ¿Muestra algo, no muestra nada? Abre la consola del navegador mientras estés probando el código. Verifica que `display.php` está en la carpeta correcta (o deberás modificar el parámetro `url`). Verifica también los logs de error. Muestra qué manejo de datos haces en `display.php`, por ejemplo no estás pasando nada en el parámetro `data`  de Ajax, por lo que el servidor no estaría recibiendo nada realmente. Deberías poner algo así más o menos: `data: { id : id}` para que PHP reciba el valor y recuperarlo con `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Tu petición Ajax está incompleta, si quieres pasar el valor de `id`, al servidor, debes poner un parámetro `data` donde pases dicho valor.

Supongo que habrás depurado las cosas básicas, como verificar que estás incluyendo bien la biblioteca jQuery, que realmente se está recogiendo bien el `id`, etc.

Te propongo este código, usando funciones más actuales de jQuery (por ejemplo `success` fue declarado obsoleto en jQuery 3, del mismo modo `type` es antiguo) y vamos a poner una función `fail`  que permitirá determinar si el fallo ocurre en el servidor.

### Javascript

```
$("#ciudad_id").change(function(){
    $("#Validar").show();
    /*Conviene poner esto en el contexto de la llamada*/
    var id = $(this).val();
    var toPost={id: id};
    alert (toPost); /*Prueba, lo quitas si ves el objeto correcto*/

$.ajax({
        method: "GET", /*type es obsoleto*/
        /*Si display.php no está en la misma carpeta debes indicar la carpeta o poner retroceso ...*/
        url: "display.php",
        /*Debes poner un parámetro data cuando haya que pasar datos*/
        data: toPost,              
        dataType: "html"   //expect html to be returned                
        /*success es obsoleto desde jQuery 3*/
        }).done( function(response) {
            alert( 'Success!!' +response ); /*Prueba, lo puedes borrar luego*/
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        /*Sirve para controlar si hubo errores en el servidor*/ 
        }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( 'Error: '+textStatus );
        });
});
```

#### PHP

Lo primero es que `display.php` debe estar correctamente indicado en el parámetro `url` de Ajax. Si no está bien, si está en otra carpeta, etc, debes indicar la ruta correcta donde está.

Segundo, debes prestar atención al `method` que indicaste en Ajax. Si indicas `GET`, significa que aquí debes usar `GET`.

Puedes hacer una verificación así:

```
#Buscamos id, porque fue lo que pasaste en data de Ajax
$id=!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;

if($id) {
    #Aquí usar $id para lo que sea, recuperar los datos y devolverlos
    #Para que no te líes demasiado, primero ponemos algo simple
    $outPut="Funciona, he recibido el valor $id y voy a trabajar con él";
}else{
    $outPut="No se postearon datos";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Con esos ajustes básicos no deberías tener problemas en tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias
Al final use otro código, adaptando otro que encontré aquí en stack y me funciona. 
Pero gracias igualmente